# Max texturepack resolution without mods

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

What is the max resolution a texturepack can have without installing any other mods like Optifine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

512x512 resolution is the highest. It can be pretty insane though. 256x256 is more common. Here's a planet minecraft page about it, I think they have some good opinions on them. [LINK](http://www.planetminecraft.com/blog/which-texture-pack-resolution-is-the-best/)(warning: link doesn't provide information specifically on 512x512, only up to 256x256, but it does talk about above 256x256)

Comment: Ah, I was wondering this too. Last time I played minecraft, the limit was 64x64.

Comment: @ardaozkal it's pretty insane on the larger resolutions, you have to have a decent computer, then it's amazing.

Comment: 512 without mods? Insane!

Comment: @TrudleR I've done it...

Comment: @TrudleR you would just need a very good computer

Comment: Yeah I just tried it out bro. With the 256 it runs ok, but with 512 I have literally 1 FPS, lol (without a notable difference). Thank you for the information. I heard that they raised the limit to 64x64 once (was not sure if true), but I didn't think that you could go this high. I think I won't go higher than 64 anyways.

Comment: @TrudleR your very welcome